# Can swimming after having eaten make you drown?

Tags: medical-science

Some people, including my mom, believe that it's very dangerous to bathe after having eaten without waiting approximately 1 hour (the amount of time depends on what you have eaten).

I have two questions:

- Is this a real danger?
- Are the chances of this happening worth giving up bathing? For example, the danger of someone dropping a vase on your head is real, but due to its unlikelihood we don't avoid walking under balconies.

Comment: If you don't eat plumb, there isn't much danger, except if you always fell asleep after eating. ;)

Comment: A bit late here, but I think some clarification is needed. Can we assume that by bathing you mean swimming, not just having a bath? And better answers might have been obtained if you had mentioned cramp: As @Brad comments, that is the common understanding of the causal link between eating and drowning...

Comment: It's just a well-known mummies-trick, to prevent kids from eating too much ice-cream or french-fries at the beach.

Comment: would it be better to change "bathing" to "swimming" in the title? In the US, "bathing" exclusively means getting into a bath tub, but i think "swimming" means the same thing everywhere in the English-speaking world

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you eat a lot, you'll feel rather uncomfortable doing any physical exercise immediately after. As for getting stomach cramps and dying, though, that has never happened. [So says snopes](http://www.snopes.com/oldwives/hourwait.asp):

> Whether oxygen-deprivation stomach cramps are real or not is open to debate, as is whether they can be brought on by eating right before engaging in strenuous activity. **What's not in doubt, however, are the lack of deaths associated with swimming right after eating — there hasn't been so much as one drowning attributed to this, not even a near drowning.** For something that was supposed to be fatal if you so much as dipped a toe, this particular old wives' tale proved to be a dud.

My emphasis...

See snopes for deeper sources.

Comment: I was swimming up river after eating a lot, then suddenly couldn't move my limbs. What kept me alive was that I could stay afloat until the river flow carried me to one of its margins.

Comment: Sounds really very scary, @Jader. Also sounds "post hoc, ergo prompter hoc." If it happened to me, and I didn't have an alternative explanation, I think I'd be going for a medical check-up shortly afterwards.

Comment: Anedoctaly sometimes large ingestion of food comes along with large ingeston of alcohoolic beverage and that's a real risk factor when swimming

Comment: @JaderDias - If you were having trouble breathing, it was probably [cold water shock](http://www.coldwatersafety.org/ColdShock.html). Which results in "Hyperventilation also results in hypocapnia, a reduction of the level of carbon dioxide in your blood which can cause: Dizziness. Faintness. Ringing or buzzing in your ears. Numbness of your fingers and toes. Cramping of your hands and feet. Reduced ability to complete simple and familiar tasks. Loss of consciousness."