# Has anyone ever died because they went swimming to soon after eating?

Tags: medical-science

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it true that bathing after having eaten can make you drown?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-it-true-that-bathing-after-having-eaten-can-make-you-drown)

There seem to be a widespread belief that going swimming after eating is really bad. [How stuff works has an article](http://health.howstuffworks.com/human-body/systems/digestive/question510.htm) on this that claims it's a good advice and it attempts to reason about it medically (though I'm unconvinced about any actual danger). From my perspective swimming just seem like any other physical activity, and it's hardly like you get incapacitated even if you get cramps.

So my question is. Has there been a single death recorded that can be reasonably attributed to getting cramps due to swimming to soon after a meal?